# How to post to another ASP.NET page from another page in a call to return to that page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post, redirect

I have a ASP.NET page that takes some key, value data and a HttpFileCollection object that is posted to it and returns a string, I want to write a page that gets this data and calls the other page and then recieves the data - kind of like a proxy as I want this page to do something with that returned data that calling the page I want directly won't do.
so need to call me.example.org/save.aspx from other.example.org/upload.aspx so that upload receives the data from that page then does something with this data, the Save.aspx is a simple web service which I only need to use the data from it in the Upload.aspx page, is this even possible, I don't need to affect the post variables just pass them to the new page and return it's data all inside the page.

Comment: Why not define the re-usable functionality in re-usable library methods instead of contriving a strange way. It is no doubt possible, but I can't fathom why one might want to do this when the pages are within the same code-base.

Comment: They aren't I just was using those as an example the other URI is not on the same domain, will change this to make it more clear.

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid If they aren't in the same code-base, how do you expect to edit the external page to return to yours if you 'transfer' the request? This isn't a technical aspect of your question _per se_, but a prerequisite of thinking such a task might be possible.

Comment: Calling the page with the given post values returns the data I want, but I need this to be called from the page I create and returned to the page I create, but it might be something I can't do - hence the question and why I might not be able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to do it your way I'd take a look at WebRequest.

The rabbit hole begins here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Indeed I think this might be the way to go, was starting to look at this anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround:

- Get the initial data into page1.
- Put it in a `HiddenField` control.
- Add an Asp.Net button to page1.
- Modify the Attribute/Property `PostBackUrl` of the button to point to page2.
- Entire form (incluiding HiddenField) will be available in page2 when Postback occurs.

Page1.aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" />
```

Page2.aspx.cs:

```
Response.Write(Request.Form["hidden"]);
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't think this is an answer in this context. As OP said **the Save.aspx is a simple web service which I only need to use the data from it in the Upload.aspx page**  Then What made you think about the Hidden Field ?